# StoryBoard fails to push segue with Could not find a navigation controller for segue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

[image]

I have a UIViewController with a container view within it.
Within the container view I have embedded a UITableViewController called CategoryTableViewControler.

CategoryTableViewControler loads up the data for displaying the rows and on clicking a cell it pushes a new CategorySecondViewController using

```
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CatOneToTwo" sender:self];
```

When I attempt to do this I get an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'CatOneToTwo'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

I understand from the forums that this is because of a missing UINavigationController, however this is present.
I'm guessing in this case that the first CategoryTableViewController within the Container view does not have access to the NavigationController.

I found the following code to prove this which is in CategoryTableViewController:

```
    // Perform Segue
if (self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CatOneToTwo" sender:self]; //<<does not get here
}
```

So question is how do I access the NavigationController here?

As you can see from the image CategorySecondViewController will be doing a similar thing with CategoryThirdViewController as well so I need something that will handle the three levels of pushed scenes.

Comment: Did you named a Segue, `CatOneToTwo` and saved your StoryBoard file ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the segue is connected to your view controller containing the container view and not to the UITableViewController inside. You could implement `UITableViewDatasource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in your UIViewController to handle tablew view content and remove the extra table view controller.

Comment: thanks, and that makes sense - eventually I simply re-used the datasource for the table viewcontroller and just redisplayed when it changed.